# Is quantum superposition is real or is it due to the fact that we measure everything in probabilities like tossing a coin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

I know not much about Quantum mechanics but I know some basics in Quantum mechanics.

when a tossed coin is in air we cannot say what state it is in currently until we catch it (or 'measure it' in quantum terms).

so can we take it as the coin is at both states at same time?

What i am asking is that **is Quantum superposition real** or is quantum superposition is same (and simple) as tossing a coin (since we measure in probabilities).

Comment: No, they are not the same. You may want to read about the two-slit experiment - the outcome is rather different for bullets that can pass through eitehr slit with some probability and for the electron waves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite like that. A better classical analogy might be a plucked guitar string. The string can vibrate in a number of 'normal modes' of vibration, each of which has a pure frequency, but when you pluck a string it tends to vibrate in a mixture of the modes with no single frequency. It is not that you don't yet know what the frequency is (as is the case with your spinning coin when you don't know how it will land), but that there is no single frequency- it is vibrating in a genuine mix of its normal modes.